# Custom Views filter for multi-level taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I'm struggling to set up two kinds of views for displaying multi-level taxonomy. One would list terms that are final nodes, and the other would list nodes that have children. Somehow, I can't.

I stated that what I really need is a filter criterion "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth=1) which have children". Does anyone know of a module/add-in that would add such a filter criterion, or perhaps knows how to define a native Views equiv (I'm still too fresh to say if that is possible).

Thanks
Artur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Relationships you add:
 Taxonomy: Parent item

then in Filters add:
 Taxonomy: Term ID, set Relationship to the above Parent, and the Operator: Is empty(NULL)

This way you only get the top level terms, because they don't have parents. Or you set it to Not empty(NOT NULL) to get the child terms.

I hope this method helps you in some way.